# Fast string comparison of strings with exact length in C

Tags: c, string, algorithm

Does anyone has an idea what will be the fastest way of a string comparison for strings with exactly 6 chars ?

My idea is the following:

```
inline bool jfStrEq6(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    uint64_t s1ui64 = *((uint64_t *)s1);
    uint64_t s2ui64 = *((uint64_t *)s2);

    return (s1ui64 & 0x0000ffffffffffff) == (s2ui64 & 0x0000ffffffffffff);
}
```

Comment: Remember that not all CPU's have the same byte order.

Comment: That may run into alignment issues, and read unallocated memory.

Answer (score 9):

This is undefined behavior: you read past the last valid byte of a 6-character string. Only seven, not eight, bytes are OK to read. In addition, byte order matters: you may need `0xffffffffffff0000` on some architectures.

If you know the length of your string, use `memcmp`:

```
inline bool jfStrEq6(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    return !memcmp(s1, s2, 6);
}
```

Chances are, your optimizer will convert this to a CPU intrinsic for a fastest comparison possible on your platform.

Comment: As a minor stylistic point, consider using `== 0` since `memcmp()`'s return value is not boolean. I realize it does the right thing as written, too.

Answer (score -2):

what do you think of xor?

return !(s1ui64 ^ s2ui64);

But I'm not sure if it is really faster, but at least shorter.

Comment: Explanation: if a bit is unequal, the result is 1. Therefore the same strings should result in zero.
If any bit is different, the result of xor is not zero. Therefore it might work (did not test it), but since I got already two negative votes, it probably does not work?

Comment: Assuming we are on x86[-64], assuming we can always read 8 bytes and not segfault, this is indeed fastest (around 20% faster than ui32 and ui16 on my machine), but you should mask garbage bytes (it remains the fastest even then).

Comment: @zen My -1 is due to ignoring the dangers of this approach, see dasblinkenlight's answer for discussion thereof.